# Convert terminal input to python dictionary for use with API

Tags: python, api, dictionary, terminal, python-requests

```
$ curl https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint \
  -u YOUR_API_KEY: \
  -d 'segments[0][origin]=ARN' \
  -d 'segments[0][destination]=BCN' \
  -d 'segments[1][origin]=BCN' \
  -d 'segments[1][destination]=ARN' \
  -d 'cabin_class=economy' \
  -d 'currencies[]=SEK' \
  -d 'currencies[]=USD' \
  -G
```

I have the following input, provided as an example by the creators of the API. This input is meant to be used in the terminal and give output in form of a dictionary. How would it be possible to write the input above in a list or dictionary to use it as part of an Python script? I tried it like below but the response from the API is solely `b' '`

```
payload = {
    "segments" : [
        { 
            "origin" : "ARN",
            "destination" : "BCN"
        },
        { 
            "origin" : "BCN",
            "destination" : "ARN"
        }
    ],
    "cabin_class" : "economy",
    "currencies" : [
        "SEK", "USD"
    ]
}

r = requests.get('https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint', auth=('my_API_key', ''), data=payload)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: 1. did you omit the YOUR_API_KEY value in curl? 2. try post instead of get? 3. `print(r.status_code)` and `print(r.reason)`

Comment: I get the response 404, Not Found. This is weird because when vomiting the curl with the correct API_Key, there is a response

Comment: What is `test`? Did you mean `data=payload`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I mean data = payload

Comment: I think you should be using `requests.post`, not `requests.get`.

Comment: i just did some test with the curl syntax. seems the -d k-v pairs finally go to parameters, not body. so suggest you try `requests.get(..., params=)`, [ref](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: @LeiYang The `curl` man page says that `-d` "Sends the specified data in a POST reques"

Comment: @Barmar the `-G` option modifies that behaviour.

Comment: When I use params= instead of data=, I get a terrible long HTML- message back and not the response it is supposed to give as per the API (https://api.goclimate.com/docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a GET request with `requests`, but you are trying to pass `data`, which would be appropriate for making a POST request. Here you want to use `params` instead:

```py
response = requests.get(
    "https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint",
    auth=("my_API_key", ""),
    params=payload, 
)

print(response.content)
```

Now, what should `payload` be? It can be a dictionary, but it can't be nested in the way you had it, since it needs to be encoded into the URL as parameters (N.B. this is what your `-G` option was doing in the curl request).

[Looking at the docs](https://api.goclimate.com/docs) and your `curl` example, I think it should be:

```py
payload = {
    "segments[0][origin]": "ARN",
    "segments[0][destination]": "BCN",
    "segments[1][origin]": "BCN",
    "segments[1][destination]": "ARN",
    "cabin_class": "economy",
    "currencies[]": "SEK",  # this will actually be overwritten
    "currencies[]": "USD",  # since this key is a duplicate (see below)
}

response = requests.get(
    "https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint",
    auth=("my_API_key", ""),
    params=payload, 
)

print(response.content)
```

Thinking of how we might parse your original dictionary into this structure:

```py
data = {
    "segments" : [
        { 
            "origin" : "ARN",
            "destination" : "BCN"
        },
        { 
            "origin" : "BCN",
            "destination" : "ARN"
        }
    ],
    "cabin_class" : "economy",
    "currencies" : [
        "SEK", "USD"
    ]
}

payload = {}

for index, segment in enumerate(data["segments"]):
    origin = segment["origin"]
    destination = segment["destination"]
    # python 3.6+ needed:
    payload[f"segments[{index}][origin]"] = origin
    payload[f"segments[{index}][destination]"] = destination

payload["cabin_class"] = data["cabin_class"]

# requests can handle repeated parameters with the same name this way:
payload["currencies[]"] = data["currencies"]
```

... should do it.

Comment: I'm surprised that `requests` isn't able to convert the nested dictionaries and lists to this format automatically.

Comment: really bad api design in my opinion. unless it is designed for confusing users.

Comment: It might be worth experimenting to see whether it can be handled automatically by `requests`, but it doesn't strike me as a standard API design pattern, so I was sceptical. I think there's likely some bespoke parsing of the incoming parameters on the server side.

Comment: This way it worked! Thank you! Is there an easy way, to create an iteration for the data "payload" in which the data always gets transformed into URL parameters?

Comment: @MisterCoder I've added that as an edit. I realised there was an issue with the original too, in that the repeated `"currencies[]"` key would just be overwritten in dictionary format. There are alternatives, but some reading (based on @Barmar's comment) made me realise you can just pass a Python list for repeated parameters.